How can I show the x-axis and with its title across all panel figures in R?
I successfully made a panel figure using a code I found elsewhere on Stack Overlfow. The only thing I am struggling with is showing the X-axis across all panel figures, as well as the label for the X-axis. I think much of the difficulty comes from having to deal with the coord_flip() function.
I looked online, and I found workarounds, such as using the facet_rep_grid() function. I tried implementing it into my code, but it throws the label for each figure to the side (see 'Example' below, please). Also, I still cannot incorporate the X-axis label ("OR (95% CI)") under each figure.
forest <- ggplot(
  data = tester, 
  aes(x = treatmentgroup, y = or, ymin = low_ci, ymax = up_ci)
) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(col = treatmentgroup))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, colour="red")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("OR (95% CI)")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = low_ci, ymax = up_ci, col = treatmentgroup), width = 0, cex = 1)+
  facet_wrap(~X, strip.position = "top", nrow = 10, scales = "free_y")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0f5765", "#007889", "#11cad0" ,"#8fd0dd")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(), strip.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA),
    strip.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = col_grid, size = 0.5),
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 13),
  )+
  facet_rep_grid(vars(X), scales = "free"
                 , space = "free",
                 repeat.tick.labels = T)+
  coord_flip()

Example

coord_flip hasn't been needed for several years now. You can swap your x and y, use xmin and xmax instead of ymin and ymax, and skip the coord_flip() entirely.

@GregorThomas even after removing coord_flip and swapping all of the mentioned variables as you recommended, the graph label for each figure is relocated to the right side when using the facet_rep_grid function. Though I am a novice in R, I think that this is an inherent characteristic of using facet_rep_grid or similar functions like facet_grid2. I am still searching online for workarounds without much success. Perhaps I will have to adopt a completely different approach when constructing the panel figures.

Why not just create three separate plots and stitch them together? That is essentially what you are describing.

I agree with Allan, it will be easier to make the three plots and use e.g. patchwork to combine them. Facets make the most sense if you want to make a single cohesive multi-panel figure since it nicely deals with repetitive elements like axis labels, which is not what you want. You can add a label for each graph with labs(title = "you_title")

I wanted to use this approach because I was aiming to stitch a table next to the figure with ORs and P-values whilst ensuring that the table rows align perfectly with each model. I adjusted my approach by making stitching one figure and its corresponding table together, and then laying all figures+tables on top of each other, which did the trick! Thanks @AllanCameron and @Axeman!
